# Does Meteor take advantage of multiple core systems?

Tags: meteor

Does Meteor take advantage of multiple core processors? Is there a configuration option that needs to be set?

Comment: Its probably more a node thing & a fibers thing but it doesn't look like multiple cores would be an advantage of http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/ for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, Meteor does not take advantage of multi core processors.

The reason is simple: Meteor is based on node.js, and by definition node.js will not automatically scale to multiple CPUs or CPU cores.

You may wonder if it's possible to somehow 'force' it to leverage multiple cores. Well, I think the answer to that is 'maybe, but not easily'. Recently node.js has included the cluster module http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html which allows you to start child processes that return eventually. It might be a  good use case for you, say if you are doing image manipulation on a large scale or something similar. But I'm not aware of any Meteor-native way of enabling this.

If you're looking at this from the point of view of scaling, you could try to fire up a node process per core by setting core affinity using Taskset on *nix, then spawn a meteor instance on each. That *might* work but my gut feel is your hardware is more likely to choke on I/O instead of CPU. Furthermore, at the moment it's not possible for two meteor servers to talk to each other.

You may have more luck when Meteor goes V1 - see this Trello note on the roadmap regarding server-to-server communications: https://trello.com/c/RKEYpJ4P/46-multitier-server-architecture-support-very-large-numbers-of-simultaneous-clients.

Finally, keep in mind that Meteor is still in development, and that Galaxy might (I'm speculating here) support multi-core processing. Galaxy is the meteor platform the team at MDG is currently working on. You can read more about this project on http://www.meteor.com/blog/2012/07/25/meteors-new-112-million-development-budget

I hope this helps.

Comment: Small correction, multiple Meteor servers can talk to each other using either the meteor-cluster smart package (running over redit), or it's successor, smart-collections (which uses the mongo oplog).

So yeah, if you have a different mongo process on each core, with a load balancer in front of it, and with one of those smart packages, you can scale easily... although unless your app is crazy resource intensive I'm in doubt a single app needs more than 1 core.

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Scaling_your_Meteor_App

Comment: sorry, i retract my "won't need more than 1 core" comment... of course ultimately for really big apps you want to scale properly.  and as per the above, you can.  consider also using a PaaS provider which makes this a lot easier (they'll handle all this stuff for you as long as you have one of the smart packages above installed, and the PaaS provider has their load balancer set up with session affinity).

Comment: Edit: since my post a lot of work has been done around scaling Meteor prior to the Galaxy release (currently rumored to land Q1 2014). I particularly recommend this article from Arunoda:  http://meteorhacks.com/how-to-scale-meteor.html

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can get the Multiple Cores with Meteor via [Cluster](https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster).
This is what you've to do.

First add cluster package:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:kadira
```

Then expose this env. variable when running your app:

```
export CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT=auto
```

For more information follow this [article](https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-multi-core-support-for-meteor.html).